# How to loop the gawk command

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract specific columns from a file using gawk command, but I need to do this several times.

```
gawk -F" " '{print $2, $7, $8, $9}' acr30R_vs_acr30NR_1.assoc.logistic >>/mnt/jw01-aruk home01/projects/jia_mtx_gwas_2016/common_files/output/imputed_dataset/all_50_mi_datasets/acr30R_vs_acr30NR_combined_coefficients/acr30nr_r_logistic_1.txt

gawk -F" " '{print $2, $7, $8, $9}' acr30R_vs_acr30NR_2.assoc.logistic >>/mnt/jw01-aruk-home01/projects/jia_mtx_gwas_2016/common_files/output/imputed_dataset/all_50_mi_datasets/acr30R_vs_acr30NR_combined_coefficients/acr30nr_r_logistic_2.txt

gawk -F" " '{print $2, $7, $8, $9}' acr30R_vs_acr30NR_3.assoc.logistic >>/mnt/jw01-aruk-home01/projects/jia_mtx_gwas_2016/common_files/output/imputed_dataset/all_50_mi_datasets/acr30R_vs_acr30NR_combined_coefficients/acr30nr_r_logistic_3.txt
```

The above code is to extract and print from 3 files (with suffix 1 , 2 and 3 as highlighted). I want to be able to do this for upto 50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a shell loop:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3); do
    gawk -F" " '{print $2, $7, $8, $9}' acr30R_vs_acr30NR_${i}.assoc.logistic >>/mnt/jw01-aruk-home01/projects/jia_mtx_gwas_2016/common_files/output/imputed_dataset/all_50_mi_datasets/acr30R_vs_acr30NR_combined_coefficients/acr30nr_r_logistic_${i}.txt
done
```

You can replace the `1` and `3` values as appropriate in the first line. Note `${i}` in the second line (in two places): these are replaced by each value in the sequence, in turn.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thank you for answering this so quickly, and it is working as expected. Regards - Sam